# If using sum>100, sums under 100 will still show

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have a table with some data. Many of these data have the name `ICA Supermarket` with different sums for every data. If I use the following SQL query, it will also show data with the sum under 100. This applies also if I change `>= '100'` to a higher digit, for an example 200.

```
SELECT *
FROM transactions
WHERE data_name LIKE '%ica%'
AND REPLACE(data_sum, '-', '') >= '100'
```

[image]

If I change `>=` to `<=` no data will show at all. Here's how the table looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `transactions` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `data_name` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `data_sum` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
)
```

Is it because `data_sum` is a `DECIMAL`? How can I prevent this from happening? I want to use `DECIMAL` for sums :)

Note: `data_sum` will also contain sums that are above minus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`REPLACE(data_sum, '-', '')` returns a string. Also `'100'` is a string. So a string compare will be used. You should use [ABS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_abs) function:

```
SELECT *
FROM transactions
WHERE data_name LIKE '%ica%'
AND ABS(data_sum) >= 100
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for values >= 100 and <= -100?  Or just values <= -100.

If the latter, then

```
... AND data_sum <= -100
```

This applies to DECIMAL, INT, FLOAT, etc.

Every table 'needs' a PRIMARY KEY.  Promote that UNIQUE to PRIMARY.